# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras' has no attribute 'model' when executing Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, import

Im currently using Tensorflow 2.3.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 3.5.

Im trying right now to code a neural network for the first time and i ran into one issue.

Here is my code rn:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np


class D3QN(tf.keras.model):
     def __init__(self,n_actions, input_shape):
          super(DuelingDeepQNetwork, self).__init__()
          self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 5, strides=(5, 5),padding="valid", input_shape=input_shape, activation="relu", data_format="channels_first")
          self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, strides=(2, 2),padding="valid", activation="relu", data_format="channels_first")
          self.conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 2, strides=(2, 2),padding="valid", activation="relu", data_format="channels_first")
          self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')
          self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='None')
          self.A = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_actions, activation='None')
     def call(self,state):
          x = self.conv1(state)
          x = self.conv2(x)
          x = self.conv3(x)
          x = Flatten()(x)
          x = self.dense1(x)
          V = self.V(x)
          A = self.A(x)

          Q = (V + (A - tf.math.reduce_mean(A, axis=1, keepdims=True)))
```

So and when executing this i got following error message:
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras' has no attribute 'model'

So i tried to google first and to fix it and people on github and here on stackoverflow said that it can be resolved by simply importing this:
import tensorflow.keras.Model
I tried that and it resulted in this error message:
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.Model'

What do i have to do to get my code running? It isnt even finished yet and i run into a weird problem like this.
I would really appreciate any help to resolve this issue

Regards

Answer (score 2):

you can use as
`from tensorflow.keras import keras`

Comment: That gives `ImportError: cannot import name 'keras' from 'tensorflow.keras'`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the following:

> `class D3QN(tf.keras.model):`

to

```
class D3QN(tf.keras.Model):
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model

--

If you want to import Model. You can use:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Stupid mistake on my side.
I sometimes forget to check which words need to start with a capital letter